# Minimum length subarray having MEX greater than or equal to k

Tags: arrays, data-structures

An array A of size N is given. Find the minimum subarray whose MEX value is greater than or equal to K.

[MEX: Minimum Excluded Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=The%20name%20%22mex%22%20is%20shorthand,nim%2Dvalues%20to%20impartial%20games.)

I just wanted to understand the algorithm to solve it.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. We expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](/help/how-to-ask) and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a binary search with a sliding window technique.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

bool go(int mp[],int k)
{
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(mp[i]==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool check(vector<int> &a,int m,int k)
{
    int mp[1002]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<m-1;i++)
        mp[a[i]]++;
    for(int i=m-1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        mp[a[i]]++;
        if(go(mp,k))
            return true;
        mp[a[i-m+1]]--;
    }
    return false;
}

void solve()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    int low=k,high=n,ans=1e9;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(check(a,mid,k))
        {
            ans=min(ans,mid);
            high=mid-1;
        }
        else
            low=mid+1;
    }
    cout<<(ans==1e9?-1:ans)<<'\n';
}


int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);
    solve();

    return 0;
    
}
```

Output:

```
5 3
4 2 4 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do this in `O(N)` time complexity

```java
public static int search(int arr[], int k) {
    HashMap < Integer, Integer > map = new HashMap < > ();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n = arr.length;
    int res = 10000000;
    //simple two pointer solution
    while (i < n) {
        //we will only consider elements which are less than k so when map size will be equal to k then this means we have found a subarray with MEX >=k then we will start removing element from map from the left side till our MEX>=k
        if (arr[i] < k)
            map.put(arr[i], map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0) + 1);
        while (map.size() == k) {
            res = Math.min(res, i - j + 1);
            if (arr[j] < k)
                map.put(arr[j], map.get(arr[j]) - 1);
            if (arr[j] < k && map.get(arr[j]) == 0)
                map.remove(arr[j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (res == 10000000)
        return -1; //if MEX>=k does not exists then ans=-1
    return res;
}
```